# Cannot navigate to new view controller by tap to cell of searchResultTable

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I am new to Objective c. I have a table with a search bar. **My problem is when i tap to a cell in searchResultTable at first time, it navigated to another view controller, but when i canceled the search and did it again and tap to the search result cell, nothing happened. Can anyone help me to solve this?** Here is some of my code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UIViewController *newView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    if(tableView == self.tableView) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
        newView.title = [[listOfGroups objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
        newView.title = [[searchData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    [newView release];
}
```

and here is some code in Viewdidload method

```
searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.delegate = self;
```

and can you clarify for me how the 3 lines of code above work, what 's it mean?
Thank you.

Comment: You can read about delegates [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html). This lines configure searchDisplayController -> "ask me (`self`) about all info that you need". `self` is a link to the current VC.

Comment: @DanSkeel : thank you, can you solve the the problem that i shown above (in bold).

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that would cause the problem you report. You should do some logging to see what's going on. Is didSelectRowAtIndexPath called the second time? Do you make it into the if tableView ==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView clause? Is self.navigationController non nil?

Comment: I did some logging as your advice. When i did the search at first time and tapped to the result cell, the method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" was called. Then i canceled the search and did it again, from that time the method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" wasn't called even if i tapped the search result cell.

Answer (score 0):

Each table view in an application needs to have a **delegate** and a **dataSource** associated with it.

The **dataSource** implements the **UITableViewDataSource** protocol, which basically consists of a number of methods that define title information, how many rows of data are to be displayed, how the data is divided into different sections and, most importantly, supplies the table view with the cell objects to be displayed.

The **delegate** implements the **UITableViewDelegate** protocol and provides additional control over the appearance and functionality of the table view including detecting when a user touches a specific row, defining custom row heights and indentations and also implementation of row deletion and editing functions.

Source: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Simple_iPhone_Table_View_Application#The_Table_View_Delegate_and_dataSource

Comment: thank you, can you solve the problem that i shown above (in bold).

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath when you are presenting the view controller and tap the search results cell. Is the breakpoint ever hit?

Comment: It hit at the first search but from the second search it didn't.

Comment: How did you add the Search Display Controller? Programatically or in the IB. If programatically, please provide more code. It looks like the delegate gets nilled after you presented the first view controller.

Comment: I did it programatically. Here is the link of my code : http://www.mediafire.com/?42y7q4y0li8hdh1. Code of search bar is in file secondViewController.m.

Comment: Ok. I found the answer. The code worked well after i added "searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self" to "viewDidLoad".